# Add comma after every link

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `ajax` call to call a handler and it's creating a link for categories that an item is in. The code works no problem, but I need to add commas and a space in between the links and I'm not too sure how.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('.Product').each(function () {

    var ProductRow = $(this);
    var ItemCode = $(this).find('.IDItemNumber').text()
    //GET UDF INFO
    $.ajax({
        url: ("/customer/somkaf/b2bse/handlers/GetItemCategories.ashx"),
        data: {
            "item_code": ItemCode
        },
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            $(response).find("Category").each(function () {
                var categoryName = $(this).find("Name").text();
                var categoryLink = $(this).find("Link").text();

                $(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append('<a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This code displays like so:

View all items in this category: Closing Wheel Assemblies and PartsFOR MONOSEMFOR WHITEKINZE CLOSING WHEELS

What I want is:

View all items in this category: Closing Wheel Assemblies and Parts, FOR MONOSEM, FOR WHITE, KINZE CLOSING WHEELS

I've tried using `join()` for the comma, like below but I get a console error that it isn't a function so maybe I'm placing it in the wrong area?

```
$(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append('<a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>').join(',');
```

Comment: When you `append `, why not add the comma inside it like: `$(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append(', <a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>');` Here you will basically `append` the comma with the link.

Comment: `.join` fails because it is an array method, not a string method

Comment: user6589814 I'll have a comma in front of the first link which I don't want, just after the 2nd link and not on the last one

Comment: okei I see. Can't you run it two times? like `$(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent:first').append('<a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>').join(',');` & after first link would be: `$(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append(', <a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>').join(',');`

Comment: Try this `jQuery('.CategoryLinkCOntent a:eq(0)').append(',');` at the end of  each function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `join` but you need to make an array out of the link instead of appending them one by one.

```js
var links = $(response).find("Category").map(function() {
  var categoryName = $(this).find("Name").text();
  var categoryLink = $(this).find("Link").text();

  return '<a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>'
}).get();

$(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append( links.join(', ') );
```

---

Or if you do not mind the comma to be part of the link you could use CSS

So you code as is, and add the following CSS rule

```
.Product .CategoryLinkContent a + a:before{content:', ';}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a CSS only solution, as it is simple in the programming part:

Create each `a` element inside a span:

```js
out += "<span class='link-container'>  <a href='#'> something </a>  </span>";
```

CSS:

```css
.link-container:not(:last-child)::after {
   content: ', ';
}
```

This will put a comma after each of the span elements excluding the last one.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, within `.each` you can choose to avoid `,` on first iteration as below:

```
$(response).find("Category").each(function (k,v) {
    var categoryName = $(this).find("Name").text();
    var categoryLink = $(this).find("Link").text();
    if(k==0)
        $(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append('<a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>');
    else
        $(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append(', <a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the success to this,

```
success: function (response) {
    var appendage = [];
    $(response).find("Category").each(function () {
        var categoryName = $(this).find("Name").text();
        var categoryLink = $(this).find("Link").text();                    
        appendage.push('<a href="' + categoryLink + '">' + categoryName + '</a>');    
    });
    $(ProductRow).find('.CategoryLinkContent').append(appendage.join(","))
}
```